# mysql: How to tail, then cat /dev/null an *.ibd file

Tags: mysql, unix, solaris

I am working on a solaris system running an optical routing EMS application that has generated an huge DATA_MAINTENANCE_LOG.ibd file.

It's taking up alot of space on the filesystem, I do not know mysql commands.

How do I effectively tail the content of this file, then safely clear it out?

Comment: Why are you using MySQL if you don't know MySQL commands? You should change one or the other of those conditions.

Comment: Agreed.  In short,  was voluntold to manage this system.  We use oracle.  This mysql db was integrated into the product by the developer.  To mgmt, all DBs must be the same thing.  Even vendor support is lacking in proper documentation and procedures for managing the tables in there.  So, the task here is to learn the commands necessary to perform a simple task that I could have done hours ago on our oracle systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I effectively tail the content of this file, then safely clear it out?

You don't, unless you like corrupting your database.

It's a database file.  Delete the data from the database table, and if you're lucky MySQL will release the file space.  If not, and your MySQL instance is configured to store one table per file, drop the table and the file will be deleted.

Any consequences from deleting data from that table, or dropping that table, are your responsibility to determine.

Comment: Good answer, but for what it's worth, it still requires doing an `OPTIMIZE TABLE <tablename>` to shrink the .ibd file after deleting data. There is no need to depend on luck. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks.  I couldn't remember that offhand.  The way I've been using MySQL recently, we've been dropping the whole table.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Once logged in, what are the commands to clear the data from this db table without dropping it?